# Laravel - Show More/Less Button conflict

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a multiple toggle button and there's something wrong when i click the first toggle button the second button has freeze and i have to double click them.

Here's the code:(

**Javascript**

```
visible = true; //var that keeps track if the content is visible.
txt6 = document.getElementById("text6");
btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6");
convert8 = document.getElementById("convert8");

function toggle7() {
    if (visible) {
        visible = 0;
        convert8.style.display = 'none';
        btn6.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Show More ';
        txt6.style.display = 'none';

    } else {
        visible = 1;
        convert8.style.display = 'block';
        btn6.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Show Less';
        txt6.style.display = 'table';
    }
}
```

**Button**

```
<button class="btn-hover color-1" id='btn6' onclick='toggle7()' style="float:left;"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Show More </button>
```

**Table**

```
<table id='text6' style='display: none; '>
    <tr>test</test>
</table>
```

**NOTE**
This toggle7 is out of 6 toggle button in the page all works fine but i have to double click the second toggle button if first toggle button are opened.
The javascript remain same for all the button and i have just change the id for elements and function name.
Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Are you using buttons inside loop ?

Comment: @TanjaForsberg Yes but i have 8 toggle buttons with different function name and elements id

Comment: I think that the element ID are repeating with the loop. It would be more clear if you could create a jsfiddle link so we can have your code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !!**

I have replace the condition with the table style where it will check if display equal none then show else hide.

Here's the code :)

```
<script>

txt6 = document.getElementById("text6");
btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6");
convert8 = document.getElementById("convert8");
function toggle7() {

  if(document.getElementById("text6").style.display == 'none') {
    convert8.style.display = 'block';
    btn6.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Show Less';
    txt6.style.display = 'table';

  } else {
    convert8.style.display = 'none';
    btn6.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Show More ';
    txt6.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for all the suggestion :) Happy Coding !

Answer (score 1):

Replace `visible = true;` to `visible = false;` and try again

Comment: I have try this and still same :( I have to double click them. Something conflict between the functions